# Transaction doesn't show up in my Blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

I am a beginner at Bitcoin. I sent my 0.0161034 BTC from LocalBitcoins to my Blockchain account. It said that it would take up to 30 minutes, but after 16 hours I still didn't get any money in my Blockchain wallet or anything to show up in the transaction history there. I also tracked my transaction on an explorer, where it's confirmed by 72 but it still doesn't show on my Blockchain wallet.

Comment: Hello, welcome to bitcoin.SE! More info is required in order to help out. Does your wallet display the same receiving address you are looking up on the block explorer? Where did you get the address you are looking up on the block explorer from?

Comment: I think you're perhaps seeing a similar issue as https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/80604/5406. You'll need Blockchain.info support to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

target your transaction on [this](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx) site. Also review [this](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000575926-I-was-expecting-to-receive-funds-but-have-not-received-them-yet)

Comment: While the links might answer the question, please include relevant information from the links in the answer itself. If the links are taken offline, this answer will not be able to help future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your wallet address and check if it matches with the receiver wallet address in blockchain. If it's right and you have good internet connection and the wallet has synced with latest block then the Bitcoins must be reflecting in your wallet.