# Urgently need advise for unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transactions

I have a transaction as below which had not confirmed for more than 2 days. May I know what is the problem or what I can I do to speed it up?

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the advise. I am using exchange wallet sending to other wallet. How to resolve this problem? As the receiver claim that blockchain show it is not receive. He is using blockchain wallet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Krivola, when you have a follow-up question usually it is best to create a new topic and link to the previous question for context. However this one is simple, either you or the recipient should get in touch with blockchain.info's support and get them to clean up their database. The transaction went through.

Answer (score 3):

Murch is correct.  Your transaction is confirmed.

```
~$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406 1
{
  "txid": "d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406",
  "hash": "82e425eade7ece29c23bf61dbc3f49326c1017fec541befc5232622a33233aa0",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 799,
  "vsize": 419,
  "weight": 1675,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [

............  
............


"blockhash": "000000000000000000214f39cdb95eb84f68c33decbd8628cecdad04da0e852a",
  "confirmations": 525,
  "time": 1540810054,
  "blocktime": 1540810054
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info is simply wrong. While it shows the transaction being unconfirmed, the transaction is actually confirmed:
[image]

See Smartbit.com.au: https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that your money cannot be lost. Eventually it will either reach its destination or revert to the sender.